# Cytoscapejs Display nodes information on the left side of the page

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I have made a cytoscapejs network. Each node has some information that I want to be displayed on the left side of the page when I click the node. The only examples I've seen with click_on events on node are super simple and only include an output on the console. Can you help me?

Comment: But what do you want to know more? Just handle this click in your framework like other user interactions.

Comment: Show us what you tried and what information the nodes contain. Also, show us what the output should look like

Comment: I think I figured out how to do this so it's fine! Thank you tho :)